# multiple language support in jsp page

Tags: jsp, character-encoding

```
<%@page pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" %>
```

While using the above directive in the JSP page, it can't display Russian and Hungarian characters in the JSP page.

Is there any way to support Russian and Hungarian characters in the same JSP page?

If I use `charset="UTF8"`, fine, or is there any other way?

Answer (score 11):

The ISO 8859-1 charset supports **only** the characters which are listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout). You'll see that it does not cover Cyrillic characters at all, only Latin characters. You **really** need to use UTF-8 instead if you want [world domination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

```xml
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

Instead of editing every individual JSP to add the `@page pageEncoding`, you can also add the following entry to your `/WEB-INF/web.xml` file:

```xml
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: Thanks Balu. If I use  UTF-8, it is support all Cyrillic characters and latin charaters also. Or still there is any problems if we will use UTF-8.

Comment: UTF-8 is an Unicode encoding which supports ALL characters the world is aware of. It has room for over one million characters: Latin, Cyrillic, Hebrew, Arabic, Chinese, Japanese, Korean, etc..etc.. ISO 8859-x encodings have only room for 255 characters. See also the linked "See also" article.

Comment: Ok, thanks Balu. I have one doubt. If I put the above <jsp-config> code in web.xml, it's work for all jsp pages are still any configurations are need.

Comment: No, not for response handling. You only need to remove `pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" from all JSP pages. You perhaps also need to implement it whenever you want to handle incoming requests. See also the linked "See also" article.

Comment: Balu, one more. If I removed pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"  attribute from page directive from all jsp's.  after If we can put  <jsp-config> in web.xml.  It's working fine or still we need any changes.

Comment: Why do you think that you need more changes if it's working fine?

Comment: Hi Balu..After using <%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %> for all jsp pages.  It's working only some jsp pages, not working for all jsp pages. Is there any alternative.

Comment: No, there is no alternative. If it doesn't work, then it means that your text source is not saved as UTF-8. Once again, read the "See also" article.

Comment: no balu.. it's working sequentially in two jsp pages. but in 3rd jsp page junk characters are taken.

Comment: As said, you need to ensure that the characters are been saved/stored/read as UTF-8.

Comment: now i got one more problem, how can save UTF-8 characters in oracle database, while I am saving Russina charaters, in databae they save like as ???????.  is there any idea for saving UTF-8 charaters in oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

Just set response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") in your servlet.