# java getParametr() returns wrang value of russian char

Tags: java, html, jsp, getparameter

I,ve got the problem with returning "letter" (russian chars) value.

The request string is: [http://localhost:8080/Library_1/pages/books.jsp?letter=Г](http://localhost:8080/Library_1/pages/books.jsp?letter=%D0%93)

// books.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@include file="../WEB-INF/jspf/left_menu.jspf" %>

<jsp:useBean id="bookList" class="beans.BookList" scope="page"/>

<%@include file="../WEB-INF/jspf/letters.jspf" %>

<div class="book_list">
    <%
        List<Book> list = null;

        if (request.getParameter("genre_id") != null) {
            long genreId = Long.valueOf(request.getParameter("genre_id"));
            System.out.println(genreId); // this string is for checking the value of returning parameter
            list = bookList.getBooksByGenre(genreId);

        } else if (request.getParameter("letter") != null) {
            String letter = request.getParameter("letter");
            System.out.println(letter);// this string is for checking the value of returning parameter
            session.setAttribute("letter", letter);
            list = bookList.getBooksByLetter(letter);
        } 
    %>
```

So, if I choose any (russian) letter I get in console "??" value instead of "Г", if I choose any genre_id (http://localhost:8080/Library_1/pages/books.jsp?genre_id=1) I get right value "1" in console.

Thanks everybody!

P. S. Browser prints the proper book list when I choose "genre" and prints empty list when I choose the russian "letter". I check the quote with the "letter" in my MySql base using inner sql quote - it works properly.

Comment: maybe reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771069/multiple-language-support-in-jsp-page can be useful to solve your problem

Comment: The value may be correct, but your console is not able to render that character. What is the console you are using?

Comment: I'm using GlassFishServer console.

Comment: P. S. Browser prints the proper book list when I choose "genre" and prints empty list when I choose the russian "letter". I check the quote with the "letter" in my MySql base using inner sql quote - it works properly.