# messy code about java web application

Tags: java

Recently, I use idea with tomcat to start my first java web application (Servlet+JSP+MySql), After I finish all the code part, I try to query some data after I add them in the application, when I use English, it's fine, when I use Chinese, there are messy code in the console, I have done everything to change the
encoding become "utf-8", but I can't solve it, help me, please！

```
public String query(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException{
    Product product = CommonUtils.toBean(request.getParameterMap(), Product.class);
    product = encoding(product);

    int pageCode = getPageCode(request);
    int pageRecord = 10;


    PageBean<Product> pageBean = productService.query(product, pageCode, pageRecord);

    pageBean.setUrl(getUrl(request));
    System.out.println(pageBean.getUrl());

    request.setAttribute("pageBean",pageBean);
    return "/content.jsp";
}

private Product encoding(Product product) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    String name = product.getName();
    if(name != null && name.trim().isEmpty()){
        name = new String(name.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"utf-8");
        product.setName(name);
    }
    return product;
}
```

the result when I was query is this:

```
/ProductServlet?method=query&barcode=&name=%E5%B8%85&units=&purchasePrice=&salePrice=&inventory=&%E6%90%9C%E7%B4%A2=%E6%8F%90%E4%BA%A4
```

the name is Chinese, but it becomes messy code

Comment: Is &搜索=提交 the correct name? Do you expect `&inventory=&搜索=提交`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple language support in jsp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771069/multiple-language-support-in-jsp-page)

Comment: `if(name != null && name.trim().isEmpty()){` doesn't make sense. You try to convert blank string

Answer (score 1):

First: `name = new String(name.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"utf-8");` should not ever be done; then something else went wrong prior to that moment.

There are the following points where an encoding/charset can be set:

- In the html `<form accept-encoding="UTF-8"...>` to indicate that the generated form field values should not be url-encoded as for instance `%E5%B8%85`.
- On the `request.setEncoding("UTF-8");` to tell that the request is in that encoding.
- On the `response.setEncoding("UTF-8");` for outgoing text.

There are many technologies that can be applied, and the settings above in reality can be done in numerous ways, as application settins, or in your case in the JSP as `<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>`.

If you are using a /WEB-INF/web.xml setting the pageEncoding for all JSPs would be:

```
<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
  </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Comment: @Michael thanks, I intended to change "not" in "never."